# Can't set my photo for stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, gravatar

I've created account for stackoverflow (by clicking change image and registering in gravatar). But picture doesn't shows. More then one day has passed since I've uploaded it. My gravatar gmail account is the same as my stackoverflow account. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My gravatar gmail account is the same as my stackoverflow account.

The email address on your account is *not* a gmail address (check your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643540/steve-yakovenko) for the main email address associated with your account). You can either change that address to match the one registered with gravatar, or you can add the email address used for your Stack Overflow account as an additional address for your Gravatar account. Either way should cause the correct picture to be shown.

Comment: And note, for Gmail, `johndoe@gmail`, `john.doe@gmail` and even `johndoe+whatever@gmail` are all the same. But: that's not true for Gravatar either. It should be an exact (lowercased) match.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. But I've changed my email and picture doesn't appear. Have I?

Comment: @SteveYakovenko Hmm, I don't know; are you sure your email as registered with gravatar is precisely identical to the one you use on Stack Overflow, character by character?

Comment: I've gave links to my profile screenshots...

Comment: @SteveYakovenko I have deleted those (not sure you want that information to be public). What is the URL of the avatar image that the gravatar page shows for you?

Comment: http://2.gravatar.com/userimage/37337696/c05a14bf37165050c5c5eadd123f4daf?size=420

Comment: @SteveYakovenko The last link in on the bottom of the blue rectangle on gravatar (it says "link" in my language) should also show your picture. That's the one I I need.

Comment: @SteveYakovenko This is what I get when I try to register on gravatar with your email address: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wXF8o.png See how the avatar it show is the anonymous grey shape? Somehow, your correct gravatar image isn't set yet. We're definitely using the correct email, so once the correct image is set, it should work.

Comment: When I click my profile, I get two images: http://s001.radikal.su/2012/07/08/1bb89fac.png default ant mine. I can't remove default nor make my own to be default.

Comment: OK, since noone can help me, let us consider this is a bug that SO actively doesn't want to fix... There are many people asking to fix that bug.

Comment: @SteveYakovenko What are you talking about? You have found out yourself that this is an issue with Gravatar, not with Stack Overflow. You'll have to talk to them; there's nothing we can do about your Gravatar account.

Comment: I've already sent them a message, no reply. Does it makes sence to deal with someone who doesn't care about their service?

Comment: At last gravatar support have managed to update my picture. Though gravatar interface is very unfriendly and hard to understand yet.

Answer (score 1):

So the gravatar you uploaded is not displaying? If you've given Gravatar's servers time to update, check your image rating: most sites will only display "G" rated images, and you may have inadvertently rated your image differently.

You can check how your image will display by using this link: en.gravatar.com/site/check